# cypress multiple commands writing on localstorage doesn't work properly

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, cypress

My use case is when a user logs in he has to select a store to navigate.

So I wanted to create commands to reuse them.

commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('username', 'bob')
})

Cypress.Commands.add('selectStore', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('storeId', 100001)
})
```

And my tests:

```js
describe('Welcome', () => {
  it('guest visits website, must login first', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/login')
  })

  it('logged in user without store selected must select a store first', () => {
    cy.login()
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/stores')
  })

  it('logged in user with store selected should visit dashboard', () => {
    cy.login()
    cy.selectStore()
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/dashboard')
  })
})
```

This suite is passing first and second test but failing third.

The problem is:

```js
cy.login() # localstorage has username key
cy.selectStore() # localstorage has storeId key but lost username key!
cy.visit('/')
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/dashboard') # cy.location('pathname') is '/login'
```

Why is happening this? Is this a bug? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I tried agoff way but it does the same:

commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.window().then((window) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('username', 'bob')
  })
})

Cypress.Commands.add('selectStore', () => {
  cy.window().then((window) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('storeId', 100001)
  })
})
```

Did you mean this?

Comment: Have you tried using `cy.window()` and then using `window.localStorage` instead of just `localStorage`? I've ran into issues when using `window.*` commands with Cypress, and alleviated many of them by using the window that Cypress yields from `cy.window()`.

Comment: @agoff I tried, edited the question. It does the same...